# Equivalence of for loop to List.get in java

Tags: java, list, foreach

I have an List with one element in it, but which may have more later. The list I am using is an ArrayList. I find that by calling List.get(0) instead of using a for loop I get faster results. Why is this? Shouldn't looping over 1 item be the same as getting  1 item? If not then how can I get similar performance? I know that my array will eventually be larger than one item. I am using this loop in the body of a opengl renderer. When I use the loop my fps drops by 45.

**Edit**: I have fixed the problem. My renderer was adding a new value to the list each time it was rendered.

Comment: "faster results"?  It's likely to be a micro-optimization that doesn't matter at all.  It'll be dwarfed by operations that fall outside your test harness.  My advice?  Don't worry about it until you measure a meaningful difference in a real application.

Comment: An example of the code that demonstrates the behaviour your describe would be very helpful.  There are many kinds of lists and many ways to write a for loop.

Comment: An ArrayList would be pretty fast at doing a direct access to an element like that.  Looping over an array list would involve at least minimal start-up (at the very least, setting up an index, starting the loop, etc. and if you used an iterator, object creation and so on.)

Comment: The arraylist is a list of meshes I am rendering using opengl. I need fast performance for something like that.

Comment: I would aim for using your loop so your code is easy to change rather than worrying about the performance. Have you measured the difference? Is it actually a problem or are you just worried about future performance?

Comment: It has a measurable impact. I go from a smooth 60 fps to 15 or lower with the for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the enhanced for loop (for-each) in Java results in compiled code that works like this:

```
Iterator<Thing> it = list.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
  yourLoop.loopBody(it.next());
}
```

You were probably expecting it to be equivalent to this ?

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
  yourLoop.loopBody(list.get(i));
}
```

but this is not the case, and constructing the iterator takes additional time that you are observing.

Comment: Even that for loop has extra overhead: It invokes an extra method and creates a new variable.

Comment: That for loop is faster, but it is still faster to skip the remove the for loop. I need this for loop for my code to work later.

Comment: You might get a small boost from checking size manually first.  The just-in-time compiler will in-line the call to size to be a direct field access.  e.g., `int size = list.size(); if (size == 1) {list.get(0);} else {for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {}}`

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the `List` implementation, a specific answer can't really be given. For example, `ArrayList` is backed by an array, so calling `get` is essentially an array access.

Using the "foreach" version of a `for` loop on the other hand requires creating an `Iterator`. This is likely the cause for a slow down. Some implementations have complex implementation for an `Iterator` or `ListIterator`.

The answer then is a question of style and readability. Most Java programmers would say the foreach loop is much more readable and clear of your intent. And with some implementations of `List` (e.g. `LinkedList`) much faster.

Comment: iterating a LinkedList shouldn't really be faster than iterating an array.  For ArrayList array access, position increment, and bounds checking are constant time.  Likewise for LinkedList, node value access, node next and bounds checking are all constant time as well.  LinkedList performs faster than ArrayList mostly when you have insertions at random points in the list (not always at the end), as LinkedList has constant time insertion, whereas arraylist does not.

Comment: @Matt, my point was that if someone did something like `for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {Object ele = list.get(i);}` it would be quite fast for an `ArrayList` and quite slow for a `LinkedList`. The reason for this is simple, one uses array access, the other has to iterate over every element until it reaches the index. Of course, in the specific case of `LinkedList`, the implementers were smart enough to iterate from the tail back if the desired index is in the last half of the list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in Collections, but setting up the iteration has got to be more expensive than simply getting a specific item.

By setting up a foreach, we don't know how many items there are in the collection, so it's going to set it up for iteration no matter how many items the list has.

Answer (score 0):

IN general, if you're worried about speed, your fastest way to go if you know you're using ArrayList would be this:

```
int size = list.size();
for (int i=0;i<size;i++) {
  Thing thing = list.get(i);
}
```

while the overhead of the "size" method is minimal, it is still overhead that need not be called in every loop.  The get() method on ArrayList is O(1).  This should give similar performance to an Iterator.  If you look at the iterator code for ArrayList, it's quite simply and the only real extra overhead is from the Object creation, and concurrent modification checking.

For LinkedList, however, this type of loop would give horrible performance as the .get() method on LinkedList is O(n), and an Iterator would be much faster, since it's simply doing a pointer check and reassignment for each iteration which makes it O(1) for each call to next().